# NullPointerException when reading from xlsx file

Tags: java, mysql, excel, nullpointerexception

I am reading data from an Excel file, which I put later in a MySQL database in the same Java program.
I had a problem adding data to the database: Eclipse kept showing a NullPointerException error.
I worked with getLastRowNum(), which also counted some empty cells after the filled cells. This problem was fixed with this code (here I only count the amount of filled cells and work with this instead of the last row number):

```
int rows = Sname.getLastRowNum();
int rows2 = 0;

for(int kk = 1; kk<= rows; kk++)
{
  XSSFRow row = Sname.getRow(kk);
  XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);

  if(cell != null)
  {
  rows2++;
  }
}
```

Last week it worked, but now I get a java.lang.NullPointerException at
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);

And I don't understand why.
Can somebody help me?
Thank you!

Comment: I think the code you provided will remain on an endless loop, since `kk` variable is not updated along the for loop. Is this the actual code?

Comment: Won't kk be updated at the end of the for loop? The 'k++' in for(int kk = 1; k<= rows; k++) will do this.
This is not the complete program, but the relevant part for the error. And yes, this is the actual code.

Comment: No. You have `int kk=1; kk <=rows; k++`. So you need to put `kk++` instead of `k++`.

Comment: Oh yes, in my program it says kk, I mistyped here, sorry. I have the error with kk, I will change it now.

Comment: If I change rows to 100, I don't get the NPE

Comment: Then `Sname.getLastRowNum();` is throwing the `NPE`...

Comment: Not at all. In fact the problem is that `Sname.getLastRowNum` is returning a value greater than 100 which makes the `Sname.getRow(kk)` throw NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `for` should begin  from `0` not from `1` and go to `rows-1`.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I start with row 1 because row 0 contains the titel of each column

Comment: And for `kk = rows` it does not return `null`? Cause if it does here is where you get your `NPE`.

Comment: Even if I put kk<rows, I stell get the NPE

Comment: Well, if you don't have empty rows in your Sheet, that could be an issue, you could try to debug the program. You will surely get to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either `Sname.getLastRowNum();` or  `Sname.getRow(kk)` are throwing NPE. Make sure you have initialized `Sname`

Also Look at your for loop:

> for(int kk = 1; kk<= rows; k++)

Does this even compile? If yes, please replace `'k++'` with `'kk++'` or else you would end up having infinite iterations.

Comment: The 'k' was mistyped, in the program it says 'kk'.
XSSFSheet Sname = workbook.getSheetAt(0); --> this is how I initialized Sname

Comment: I can print out the last row number, so there is no null value there.
How can I see if Sname.getRow(kk) throws a NPE and how can I fix this?

Comment: In that case one of the two methods called on Sname must be returning null or throwing NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the limit of the loop. It should go to `kk < rows` instead of `kk <= rows`.

In fact, before testing this solution, I would try to log the value for `Sname.getLastRowNum()` and watch what value it has.